# How to use Unicode strings with Unicode codes in Python? (ex: U+1F44D)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I use Unicode strings in Python? Say I want to use the Unicode `U+1F44D` (which is the thumbs up emoji). Do I use `u'U+1F44D'`, `u'1F44D'`, or `u'0x1F44D'`? Or should I use `chr(0x1F44D)`? I'm just not sure.

Thanks for your help, and sorry if this wasted your time.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode characters at codepoints above 0xffff can be entered as literals like this: `"\U0001f44D"`.

For characters bellow 0xffff, the four digit version uses the  `u` character, like in `\u2654`.

If you have your emoji code as numeric data during program  runtime, not at coding time, you can use the `chr` build in - actually, you can use the chr builtin all along. The inconveninence is that it yields a single character string, always:  `chr(0x1f44d)`.

Back to literals, it is also possible to use the official unicode name for the character inside a Python 3 literal string - for that, use the `\N` prefix and enclose the character name between `{}`: `"\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}"`.
If you want to fetch characters by name at runtime, use the unicodedata.lookup: `import unicodedata; unicodedata.lookup("THUMBS UP SIGN")`